# ReactJS - Passing ID through OnClick

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

I want to pass the *'ID'* and *'Value'* of a *<button>* into a function, and use it to run a piece of code. I was not able to pass the elements. I have tried the several solutions mentioned in similar questions, but was unsuccessful.

I ended up passing them as parameters, and everything works fine. But I know there must be way to do this better, by passing the ID and Value, without having to pass it as hard-coded parameters.

```
<button type="button" id="button1" name="testName" value="abc" onClick={()=>this.callFunction('button1', 'abc')}>Click Me !!</button>

callFunction(id,value) {
  console.log(id,value);
}
```

Comment: onClick={(e)=>this.callFunction(e, 'button1', 'abc')} and in the function get it from e.target.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments

Use event to get the id. Pass event to the handler function and get the id value with event.target.id

```
<button type="button" id="button1" name="testName" value="abc" onClick={event => this.callFunction(event)}>Click Me !!</button>

callFunction = (event) => {
   console.log(event.target.id, event.target.value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the event target, `e.target`:

```
<button type="button" id="button1" name="testName" value="abc" onClick={this.callFunction}>Click Me !!</button>

callFunction(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id, e.target.value)
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Although, I wanted a solution in ES6, this proves to be just as effective.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event`, check [handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

```
<button type="button" id="button1" name="testName" value="abc" onClick={(event)=>this.callFunction(event)}>Click Me !!</button>
```

or

```
<button type="button" id="button1" name="testName" value="abc" onClick={this.callFunction}>Click Me !!</button>
```

In `callFunction` you can call the read the event:

```
callFunction = (event) => {
  const id = event.target.id;
  const value = event.target.value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. This works like a charm !